# Which network protocol to use to sync resources between a server a several clients

Tags: ios, sockets, protocols, data-synchronization

I am building a professional iOS application where an iPad is a server and several iPhones are clients.

Considering the fact that :
- communications operate only on a local network via sockets using TCP.
- I want to keep all of them in sync (all devices have a local database)
- I want to be able to send commands like NEW, UPDATE, DELETE, etc to keep them in sync
- I want be able to send notifications with some data attached (audio file),
- I want to define priorities for all of theses commands.

It makes me think that a need to define a protocol, so my question is : Does one already exist ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen socket messages, server can send simple structs with data url, commands to clients, and after that they can update data for example:

```
#define MSG_DOWNLOAD 1

typedef struct{
   uint8_t cmd;
   uint8_t size;
} MSGHEADER

typdef struct{
   MSGHEADER header;
   char url[255];
} MSGDOWNLOAD;
```

and in socket if you will get header with cmd = 1, you can send NSURLconnetion with url to your server and download some data and sync it.

```
- (void)recivedDataFromBuffer:(NSData *)data
{

    MSGHEADER *pMsgHdr;
    pMsgHdr = (MSGHEADER*)[data bytes];

    int headerCMD = pMsgHdr->cmd;

    if (headerCMD == MSG_DOWNLOAD)
    {
        MSGDOWNLOAD download = *(MSGDOWNLOAD *)pMsgHdr;
        download.header = *pMsgHdr;

        // do sync stuff send url request etc.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much for you answer! But since the iPad is the server and holds all data, this means that between an iPhone and the iPad (the server) there will be 2 connections : 1 for the commands via a socket and 1 for the data retrieve, like an HTTP server on the iPad (which uses sockets too right?). So that doubles the number of connections, is it a good practice ?

Comment: It depend what do you want to do, you can use only TCP socket with command+data inside one struct but, if you don't want to sending big files as images, music you should have HTTP server. Socket will send you a link to download some big data, and easly you will retrive it. But it is also possible to use only socket but you have think about buffer problem.